# Vertically align all images & captions in a google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm looking for a script that goes through a google doc and vertically aligns all images with their captions. below linked video describes what I'd like done in greater detail:
I want it to automate the process.

[Video explanation](https://vimeo.com/497249661)

Please I need the solution fast.

Thank you in adavnce.

Comment: Could you share the sample doc here? Also the video has no sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Google Docs Services does not have any function that will align any element vertically centered within the page, only horizontally. Alternative solution is to use [PositionedImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image).

PositionedImage have `method:setTopOffset` where you can sets the image's offset, in points, from the paragraph's top.

### Reference:

[PositionedImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image)